# Why is DoCheck lifecycle hook needed in Angular?

Tags: angular

So I was reading about the [component lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks#sequence-and-frequency-of-all-lifecycle-events) and came to know that DoCheck is triggered after every change detection cycle, and is followed by AfterContentChecked and AfterViewChecked. If that is the case, then `why is the DoCheck hook needed in the first place?`. Everything that we write in the DoCheck method, can be written in the `AfterContentChecked` or the `AfterViewChecked` method as well (since they get triggered right after the DoCheck method). And since DoCheck is mostly used for debugging purposes, replacing it with the other these lifecycle hooks won't break anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngDocheck` is triggered whenever component inputs are "being checked". Also if you enable `ChangeDetectionStragegy.OnPush` and none of your inputs are changed, then no checking on the template of the component will be done. as I remember none of AfterXChecked hooks will also be called.

the valid use case for `ngDoCheck` hook is to check your inputs "deeply".

```
 interface ComplexData {
   num: number;
 }
....
 @Input() data: ComplexData;
 oldNumValue: number;
 
 ngDoCheck() {
   if(this.data?.num !== this.oldNumValue) {
     // here we have a situation where default change detection could think the 
     // value didn't change, as `data` refers to the same object
     // but its field was changed instead
     this.cdRef.markForCheck();
   }
 }
```

if you would try to do this logic in `AfterViewChecked` for example then you would get "Expression changed after being checked" error, becaus in this hook the view was already checked